# Big organization needs to have a single point (project) of requests able to create a ticket and later move it to any other projects backlogs

Tags: jira

I've tried different approaches and none of them were simple and elegant enough to make the cut.

I've created a board using a filter involving all of our company's project so yes, you can track them but when it comes to creating one from this "Support" project, there's no way to move them to another project's backlog. One way was to create an additional Sprint in every other projects and naming them "*X Team* Support Backlog" so it could be placed in a separate "backlog" to be groomed accordingly but this is just messy and overkill to me.

Other than that would be to actually *Move* the ticket in the setting to convert them to the chosen other project but then it changes the key and you lose the track from the "Support" stand point.

There has to be a simpler option that Jira offers to handle those cases and I can't seem to come up with one so far nor to find an answer to my situation when searching online.

Anyone of you had this kind of issue and what ways did you use to handle this?

Thank you in advance!

(This is actually my first question here so be gentle if I somehow did something wrong hehe)

Comment: Can you clarify why just Moving it doesn't work? If you Move S-53 to ABC-7, and then take a link to S-53, in most cases Jira *should* redirect you to ABC-7. It's smart enough to recognize that the issue was moved.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the community ! Am a newbie over here, figuring out things up here. So excited to answer.

Little context:
I had a similar issue in my previous company/startup. The customers used to raise the support ticket in the jira. We needed to track the progress of the development, deployment and few other metrics.

We created a internal ticket in jira, which is only visible to us only. We used to work on the ticket and update the status on the parent ticket. After a while , this was getting bit complex and more time was wasted by doing this.

This is how we approched the situation,

1. As soon the customer is creating the support ticket in jira. The system is able to create a duplciate ticket automatically with all details from the parent ticket and assign to a team.
2. So we used to track our progress and everything on this internal ticket. Efforts were logged and so on.
3. Once the internal ticket is released, the system will automatically resolve the parent ticket and resolution comments are auto updated.

Hope this helps.

Amnt sure about the technical aspects over this, thanks to my devops team they figured out to make things works :)

Answer (score 0):

There's a recurrent confusion about how Projects and Boards interact. I've explained it [HERE](https://pm.stackexchange.com/a/34902/430). The way the question is structured isn't clear how different teams would interact. I'm assuming when you say "another project's backlog" there's a Jira project per team.

**Short Version**

1. Stick for a single *project* for Support (only use Jira Service Desk if you really need their features, as it's pretty expensive)
2. Create "identifiers" of support for different projects
3. Change each team board filter so that items with these identifiers appear there

**A bit of needed detail**

The key is who (and how) to designate tickets per support types. It's unclear if there's a 1:1 relationship between support types and teams or there's a queue and someone distributes them evenly across different teams. Regardless, this person need to understand how these "identifiers" work and then change them accordingly.

Say you agree that the "component" field will be the identifier. In the support project, you have different components, A B and C. And you have Team X and team Y.

So, you need to change the filter in Team X board filter so that it shows its own tickets plus the tickets from support team where component is A.
Likewise, you change Team B board filter so that it shows its own tickets plus the tickets from support team where component is B or C.